# Pivot table relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have Category - Course pivot table.
it's called Directions:

```php
public $table = 'directions';

protected $fillable = [
    'course_category_id','course_id'
];
```

category:

```php
public function manyCourses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Direction::class, 'directions', 'course_category_id', 'course_id');
}
```

course:

```
public function manyCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Direction::class, 'directions', 'course_id', 'course_category_id');
}
```

and in blade i'm trying to get data from directions table but i'm getting error
Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias
I searched error and it's telling that i have relationships problem... but i think i'm doing something wrong in blade...

```xml
<select class="many-course-category" name="categoryId" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach ($c->manyCategories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->pivot->course_category_id }}">
            {{ $category->pivot->course_category_id->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

$c is my current course / course edit...

so whats i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the relationship wrong. The syntax is

```php
belongsToMany($related, $table, $foreignPivotKey, $relatedPivotKey)
```

`$related` is not the pivot model, it's the related model.

To specify the pivot model's class, you need to chain the `using()` method to your relationship. ([Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)). You might need to make your Direction model extend Pivot instead of Model in its declaration (`class Direction extends Pivot`)

Specifying a pivot model is optional.

```php
public function manyCourses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class, 'directions', 'course_category_id', 'course_id')
                ->using(Direction::class);
}
```

```php
public function manyCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'directions', 'course_id', 'course_category_id')
                ->using(Direction::class);
}
```

---

As for the blade part, like [Erich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4468423/erich) suggested, the solution is to call `$category->name`.

```xml
 @foreach ($c->manyCategories as $category)
    <option value="{{ $category->pivot->course_category_id }}">
        {{ $category->name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for response. yes now it's works but i'm getting another error it's blade error: Call to undefined method App\Models\Direction::fromRawAttributes()

Comment: likely coming from `{{$category->pivot->course_category_id->name}}` in the blade.  if you are iterating through all of the options eventually, you probably want this to be `{{$course->name}}` (after defining $course as the iteration data of course)

Comment: ops i forget to add code here... @foreach($c->manyCategories as $category) and then ${{$category->pivot->course_category_id->name}} and i'm getting error  Call to undefined method App\Models\Direction::fromRawAttributes()

Comment: @IGP thanks i changed model to Pivot now it's working i have one last question how can i get category name ? {{$category->pivot->course_category_id->name}} i'm getting ids without names but i need category names

Comment: $category->name

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping : )